# Azure chat bot in MS Teams

Tags: azure, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am trying to build an Azure bot that should be accessible via MS Teams (personal conversation only) in my own organisation and in my client's organisation. The bot does have authentication within our AD, so if someone accesses it from our internal network, it does not prompt for login. I am wondering how it is going to work for the external organisation's MS Teams.

1. How do I deploy it to their MS Teams
2. What are the authentication options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your options for limiting bot usage in specified tenants:

1. [Bots for limited tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/scenarios/limited-tenant)
2. [Microsoft Teams authentication flow for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication)

   *Note: Make sure to use Use **common** instead of hard coding **{tenant}** name in the login URL.*

For deployment, have a look at [Publish apps to the Microsoft Teams Tenant Apps Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/tenant-apps-catalog-teams) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Uploading into the Teams Tenant Apps Catalog looks like a good option. What is I am still struggling to understand is "add for you" option. I don't want to add the bot to a team, so the whole team sees the conversation, but I want the bot will be available to each employee in individual chat dialog. "add for you" is only for me, as an admin, or for all individuals?

Comment: We are working on a feature where Admin can decide which all apps are by default available for all the employees or group of employees. I don't have more details about timelines to share as of now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I found that a bot can be added to a private chat just by searching its MS App ID. Are you aware of any drawbacks in using this method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/add-bots